# PySpark Dataframe recursive column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this PySpark Dataframe calculated in my algorithm:

```
+------+--------------------+
| A    |        b           |
+------+--------------------+
|     1|1.000540895285929161|
|     2|1.097289726627339219|
|     3|0.963925596369865420|
|     4|0.400642772674179290|
|     5|1.136213095583983134|
|     6|1.563124989279187345|
|     7|0.924395764582530139|
|     8|0.833237679638091343|
|     9|1.381905515925928345|
|    10|1.315542676739417356|
|    11|0.496544353345593242|
|    12|1.075150956754565637|
|    13|0.912020266273109506|
|    14|0.445620998720738948|
|    15|1.440258342829831504|
|    16|0.929157554709733613|
|    17|1.168496273549324876|
|    18|0.836936489952743701|
|    19|0.629466356196215569|
|    20|1.145973619225162914|
|    21|0.987205342817734242|
|    22|1.442075381077187609|
|    23|0.958558287841447591|
|    24|0.924638906376455542|
+------+--------------------+
```

I need to calculate a new Column named F, as a sort of recursive calculation :

```
F(I) = F(I- 1) * 0.25 
    + b(I+ 1) * 0.50 +  b(I) * 0.25
```

When `I` is the row index, and only for `I= 1` the value of `F(1)` is:

```
f(i) = b(i) * 0.25 
    + b(i+ 1) * 0.50 +  b(i) * 0.25
```

How I should calculate that? Should I use lag and lead functions?

Comment: @Chirag: I don't think there is any easy way you can do it. This previous question could give you some idea how to do it approximately though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701250/spark-exponential-moving-average

Comment: If you showed us the whole table and it really is "small enough", i would not use spark to calculate `F` but load this thing into a hashmap and directly compute that. Also do not do that recursively but try to start just with `F(1)` and work your way up. That should be kind of small load for your call stack and fast since you only access hashmaps: one for `b` and one for `F`.

Comment: Does it need to be another column in this table or results are enough?

Comment: @Chirag Could explain your specific use case? If you're _not concerned about scaling_ then the question makes little sense. One could suggest `collect` or `coalesce(1)` and iterate which makes it hardly a Spark question.