# PySpark: Calculate Exponential Moving Average

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to calculate the exponential moving average of unit 9 of Close in PySpark

**Below is my data**

```
+---------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   Symbol|           DateTime|    Open|    High|     Low|   Close|
+---------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 09:15:00| 27235.5|27239.55| 27087.7| 27119.8|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 09:30:00| 27120.3| 27123.3|27073.85| 27103.6|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 09:45:00| 27104.7| 27119.1|27035.25| 27052.7|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 10:00:00|27051.65|27078.35| 27038.8| 27070.7|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 10:15:00|   27071|27092.85| 27061.3| 27076.9|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 10:30:00| 27078.2| 27099.1|27064.95| 27079.1|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 10:45:00|27077.85| 27094.5|27057.45|27085.65|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 11:00:00|27082.85| 27116.5|27082.35| 27112.7|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 11:15:00|27111.75| 27119.1| 27081.6|27083.35|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 11:30:00|27084.25|27106.65|27080.65| 27099.3|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 11:45:00| 27100.5|   27114| 27095.3|27109.15|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 12:00:00|27108.95|27122.85|27105.55| 27111.9|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 12:15:00| 27114.4| 27121.1|27086.55| 27087.8|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 12:30:00|27087.95|27088.45| 27060.4| 27074.3|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 12:45:00| 27072.8| 27081.7|27054.75| 27062.2|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 13:00:00|27062.35|27094.55| 27059.5|27093.15|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 13:15:00|27093.45|27094.85|27075.65|27085.05|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 13:30:00| 27084.8|27087.15|27019.05| 27043.2|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 13:45:00|27045.75|27068.85|27035.85|27062.35|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 14:00:00|27062.45|27100.35|   27057|27080.65|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 14:15:00|27081.05|27188.25| 27076.6|27188.25|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 14:30:00|27186.85|27309.45| 27179.8|27294.15|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 14:45:00| 27294.1|27356.85| 27294.1|27346.35|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 15:00:00| 27346.1|27395.35|27326.05| 27386.8|
|BANKNIFTY|2019-01-01 15:15:00|   27385|27430.55|   27380|27411.15|
+---------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Want to add the column EMA which calculate the exponential moving average of last 9 close price periods

**Formula for Calculating EMA**

```
Multiplier  = 2 ÷ (number of time periods + 1) => 2 ÷ (9+ 1) => 2 ÷ 10 => 0.2
EMA: {Price - EMA(previous row)} x Multiplier  + EMA(previous row)
```

**Desired Output**

```
+---------+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   Symbol|        DateTime|    Open|    High|     Low|   Close|     EMA|
+---------+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 09:15| 27235.5|27239.55| 27087.7| 27119.8|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 09:30| 27120.3| 27123.3|27073.85| 27103.6|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 09:45| 27104.7| 27119.1|27035.25| 27052.7|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 10:00|27051.65|27078.35| 27038.8| 27070.7|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 10:15|   27071|27092.85| 27061.3| 27076.9|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 10:30| 27078.2| 27099.1|27064.95| 27079.1|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 10:45|27077.85| 27094.5|27057.45|27085.65|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 11:00|27082.85| 27116.5|27082.35| 27112.7|        |
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 11:15|27111.75| 27119.1| 27081.6|27083.35|27087.17|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 11:30|27084.25|27106.65|27080.65| 27099.3|27089.59|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 11:45| 27100.5|   27114| 27095.3|27109.15| 27093.5|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 12:00|27108.95|27122.85|27105.55| 27111.9|27097.18|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 12:15| 27114.4| 27121.1|27086.55| 27087.8|27095.31|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 12:30|27087.95|27088.45| 27060.4| 27074.3|27091.11|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 12:45| 27072.8| 27081.7|27054.75| 27062.2|27085.32|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 13:00|27062.35|27094.55| 27059.5|27093.15|27086.89|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 13:15|27093.45|27094.85|27075.65|27085.05|27086.52|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 13:30| 27084.8|27087.15|27019.05| 27043.2|27077.86|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 13:45|27045.75|27068.85|27035.85|27062.35|27074.76|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 14:00|27062.45|27100.35|   27057|27080.65|27075.93|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 14:15|27081.05|27188.25| 27076.6|27188.25| 27098.4|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 14:30|27186.85|27309.45| 27179.8|27294.15|27137.55|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 14:45| 27294.1|27356.85| 27294.1|27346.35|27179.31|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 15:00| 27346.1|27395.35|27326.05| 27386.8|27220.81|
|BANKNIFTY|01-01-2019 15:15|   27385|27430.55|   27380|27411.15|27258.88|
+---------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

Formula Link : https://sciencing.com/calculate-exponential-moving-averages-8221813.html

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54489659/4758823

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't super clear, as your test data set doesn't include multiple days, so you're EMA can't be using previous days from the data in your example.

However, to create your data set you'd need:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, StringType, StructField, StructType, TimestampType

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("Symbol", StringType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("DateTime", TimestampType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("Open", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("High", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("Low", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("Close", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("Close", FloatType(), nullable=False),
    ]
)

data = [
    ("BANKNIFTY",2019-01-01 09:15:00, 27235.5,27239.55, 27087.7, 27119.8),
    ("BANKNIFTY",2019-01-01 09:30:00, 27120.3, 27123.3,27073.85, 27103.6),
    ("BANKNIFTY",2019-01-01 09:45:00, 27104.7, 27119.1,27035.25, 27052.7),
...
]

sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
df = sql_context.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

From there, you just need to create the window

```py
w = Window().partitionBy("Close").orderBy(F.col("DateTime"))
```

And then create the new column using the window

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "EMA",
    F.avg("Close").over(w)
)
```

Note: here I'm just using a mean, rather than the EMA you requested. To get the EMA I'd add an additional column that calculates the EMA per day, and then just use that in the calculation.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Previous day means the previous row's EMA value. I need to find the EMA value only according to the standard EMA calculation. Also if I am finding EMA value of 9 then first 8 rows won't have any EMA value. From 9th row onwards we will have EMA value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case, what you need is the `lag` function. For example, `F.lag(F.col("Flag"), 9)` where 9, is the number of previous rows

Comment: could you please update your answer for EMA calculation, the answer you shared is for Simple MA calculation.